# Create Rulers for Mouse Over Follow in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

Does FabricJs have anything inbuilt to handle creating a ruler dynamically on mouseover and follow? If not, can anyone direct me on how to go about this?

Check the attached gif.

[image: CreateRulerOnMouseFollow]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/diagram/ruler/

Comment: @MuhametSmaili Thanks for the link, however it is meant to work with FabricJs.